# How do I set the second image on the more detailed addon page in Firefox Add-ons Manager?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

When I go to the Firefox Add-ons Manager (about:addons), click on Extensions and then click on the "More" link next to one of the installed addons, I see the addon icon next to the title and version of the icon, then immediately below it, there is a **second, larger image next to the add-on's description.**

Some addons put a larger logo here, others add screenshots. I have checked the "Edit Listing" page and the manifest keys, but I can't figure out how to set this image.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

[image: Mysterious second image]

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that this second image is automatically chosen from the screenshots posted on the add-on's listing, only in this case there happened to be a delay of *several hours* between the creation of the listing and the appearance of the image.